# Weird jquery error when checking for email data in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

Okay so i have a working example from jsfiddle which i cannot get to work. I used the code yesterday and now it simply doesnt work.

The code should check for duplicated emails and extract the emails from the first textarea to the second.

The link for Jsfiddle with working sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/49fkexu9/

I'm using the exact same code on my website, however it always says that theres no emails in the text.

Can anyone see an error in the code?

My website it:
http://truelads.com/email-extractor/

My html code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <textarea id="email-extractor" class="email-extractor-textarea"></textarea>
<textarea id="email-extracted" class="email-extractor-textarea"></textarea>
```

My Jquery code:

```
function extractEmails(text) {
    return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
}

function eliminateDuplicates(arr) {
    var i;
    var len = arr.length;
    var out = [];
    var obj = {};

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        obj[arr[i]] = 0;
    }
    for (i in obj) {
        out.push(i);
    }
    return out;
}

var emailsFullList = [];

$('#email-extractor').keyup(function (index) {
    var emails = extractEmails($(this).val());
    console.log(emails);
    if (!emails) {
        $('#email-extracted').val('No emails found in text');
    } else if (emails.length < 2000) {
        var text = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
            text += emails[i] + ', ';
        }
        emailsFullListCheck = emailsFullList.concat(emails);
        emailsFullListNone = eliminateDuplicates(emailsFullListCheck);
        $('#email-extracted').val(emailsFullListNone);
    } else {
        $('#email-extracted').val('Please allow a max-limit of 2000 emails (' + emails.length + ').');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a section with the id `email-extractor` and a text area with the id `email-extractor`. You will need to change one of these then make sure your js lines up with the one you want to target

Comment: Thank you. i will add your anwser in 9 min. I know this might have been stupid, but sometimes i just cant see my own errors.. Best from here and good day to you